# Why is $|V(I)| \leq d_1\cdots d_n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, groebner-basis

If $I \subset K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is a zero dimensional ideal and $$V(I) = \{ (\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n) \in K^n: f((\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)) = 0\ \forall f\in I\}$$ (the variety). Then if $G$ is a Groebner Basis for $I$ w.r.t. some monomial order $>$, then $\forall i$ $\exists g_i \in G$ such that $LT(g_i) = x_i^{d_i}$ for some $d_i > 0$. Why is $|V(I)| \leq d_1\cdots d_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x_1>\cdots>x_n$. Then $g_i=g_i(x_i,\dots,x_n)$ is a polynomial in $x_i,\dots,x_n$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

In particular, $g_n$ is a polynomial only in $x_n$. Let $\alpha_n$ be a root of $g_n$. (There are at most $d_n$ roots.) Then consider $g_{n-1}(x_{n-1},\alpha_n)$. This has at most $d_{n-1}$ roots, and let $\alpha_{n-1}$ be one of them. Now consider $g_{n-2}(x_{n-2},\alpha_{n-1},\alpha_n)$, and so on. Finally we get at most $d_1\cdots d_n$ common roots for $G$.

Comment: Excuse me, you say that $g_i = g_i(x_i,\dots,x_n)$, so say $i = 2$, then $g_2 = g_2(x_1,x_2)$. Isn't that variable polynomilal and not a polynomial in just $x_2$?

Comment: @jacobsmith Maybe you want to say $g_2=g_2(x_2)$. It seems you missed that $LT(g_2)=x_2^{d_2}$. How could $g_2$ have a monomial containing $x_1$? This will be strictly greater than any power of $x_2$.

Comment: I misread, but because you mentioned $LT(g_2) = x^d_2$, i guess the other $x_3$ wont' appear. Right.

Comment: Just one thing, you really meant to say $g_2 = g_2(x_2, \dots, x_n)$ right?

Comment: @jacobsmith Right.